# Informatica: Delete rows from multiple tables sequentially. Then Insert

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Consider the following scenario:

1. Main Control Table: 100 rows (Denormalized table with multiple processing ID's).
2. Set of 10 Parent Tables populated based on Control table.
3. Set of 10 Child Tables populated based on the Parent tables.

For daily processing:

1. We need to delete the data from Child tables first.
2. Parent Tables next.
3. Control table last.

Then insert data into Control table using multiple Insert Statements as it is denormalized.

Is this possible in one mapping?

One suggestion is to use SQL Transform and just execute the SQL's one after the other.

Is there an alternative way of Handling this?

Comment: Why the requirement to use only one mapping? What's wrong with multiple mappings ordered appropriately in a workflow?

Comment: You can create few pipelines in one mapping and make them run in desired order via setting correctly the Target Load Plan (in Mappings menu). But I'd also go with multiple mappings as Marek suggests above.

Comment: You will insert data into parent and child tables also, right?